# weird django error: cannot import name get_path_info

Tags: django

I suddenly started getting this error when I try to start the django development server, and I cannot figure out where it is coming from. I have tried updating django.

```
 File "/virtualEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/runserver.py", line 6, in <module>
from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import StaticFilesHandler
 File "/virtualEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 9, in <module>
from django.core.handlers.base import get_path_info

 ImportError: cannot import name get_path_info
```

Has anyone seen any error like this before? Definitely trying my best to figure this out...

Comment: may be you accidentally deleted or modified the file ? try reinstalling django in the virtualenv

Comment: well it was because it had been installed twice somehow (once with pip and once with setuptools...). NICELY DONE SIR!! THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, the problem was that `dj_static 0.0.5` didn't seem to be playing nicely with Django `1.7`. I upgraded to `dj_static 0.0.6` and it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.
Resolved for Django 1.7 by changing the import path for get_path_info:

from django.core.handlers.base import get_path_info

became:

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import get_path_info